# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when using chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Attempting to modify a password form in a page from an extension. This code works fine to modify a form within the extension:

```
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() === "password") {
          inputs[i].value = ("finally");
        }
      }
```

When chrome.tabs.executeScript code is added to access the page doc, I get the following error pointing towards the second line:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Here is the modified code (line 2 being the culprit according to logs):

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() === "password") {
          inputs[i].value = ("finally");
        }
      }
})
```

Am I misusing `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,` as a means to switch between the extension document and page document?

Comment: Is the second argument supposed to be a function? Because currently you are supplying what would syntactically be an object literal but it's not a correct object literal.

Comment: Yep, apparrently [second argument should be an object, third is a callback](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

Comment: Do you know how to correct it @VLAZ ?

Comment: Use the API as intended -I've linked you to the documentation that even has a link to how you should use this with examples. Since I never used this API nor am I sure what exactly are you trying to achieve, I'm not in the best position to say what exactly what you should do. I just see that you've syntactically incorrect code and you need to correct it *and* use the API correctly.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I figured it out based on your comment. I'll post the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Solution derived based on the comment above by @VLAZ. Will be glad to switch the accepted answer to one by @VLAZ if you copy/paste this answer or another.

Corrected by breaking the .js file into two js files and referencing the second one within an executeScript function:

start.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
file: 'startUp.js'
});
```

to call startUp.js

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
      if (inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() === "password") {
        inputs[i].value = ("finally");
      }
    }
```